# Create Custom prop which calls a function React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am a react beginner, i wanted to know how i can create prop like the 'OnClick' prop on standard button component on to my own custom component

```
<Button OnClick='functionName'> Button </Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick` will just be a prop like any other that you have to use in your component and e.g. pass along to the `onPress` prop of a [`TouchableOpacity`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity).

**Example**

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { onClick, children } = this.props;
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onClick}>
        <Text>{children}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```